# Detecting event on a FragmentTabHost present in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host, android-nested-fragment

**What I have**:

- I have a fragment
- I am using SherlockActionBar library
- I have a FragmentTabHost in Fragment

**What i want to know**: I want to detect `onClick` event each tab and perform some action based on it

**Fragment1.java**:

```
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment{

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;


    //Mandatory Constructor
    public Fragment1() {
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container, false);


        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentb").setIndicator("Rating"),
                RatingAscending.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentc").setIndicator("Price"),
                PriceAscending.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentd").setIndicator("Distance"),
                DistanceAscending.class, null);


        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want to do is detect when a specific tab has been clicked in your FragmentTabHost. This can be accomplished quite simply by adding a [setOnTabChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html#setOnTabChangedListener%28android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener%29). 
Here is an example:

```
FragmentTabHost t = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
    t.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            // TODO your actions go here

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: yes that swhat i was looking for .... also can u add more info on answer on ..... say .... my tab is displaying a fragment( ... say fragmentA .... now using your solution i detected the event ...... now how to load fragmentB on that event in same tab

Comment: I think you should pose that as another question

Comment: @stewjacks....  Ok please have a look at this question ... i have formulated a new one http://stackoverflow.com/q/23284232/1083093