# How to change the body of tab onClick of same tab in fragmentTabhost

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host, android-nested-fragment

**What I am doing**:

- I have a `fragmentabhost` in a fragment that has `3-tabs` in it.
- On click of tabs i am able to change the fragments dynamically
- `On click` of first tab i am displaying `RatingAscending.class`

### [image]

**What I am trying to do**:

- Now `Onclick` of the same tab I want to display
  `RatingDescending.class`

---

*Note*: in the `onResume()` I am able to detect `click event` for the `firsttab`

---

**Now how can I change the tab to  `RatingDescending.class` from `RatingAscending.class` when I click the tab for the `second time`**

[image]

---

**Fragment1.java**

```
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment{

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    private static int count=0;
    //Mandatory Constructor
    public Fragment1() {
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container, false);


        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentb").setIndicator("Rating"),
                RatingAscending.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentc").setIndicator("Price"),
                PriceAscending.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentd").setIndicator("Distance"),
                DistanceAscending.class, null);


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                count++;
                Log.d("You clicked ", count+"time");

            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- I Finally found answer myself here ([I refered this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120510/dynamically-changing-the-fragments-inside-a-fragment-tab-host/19859871#19859871)),  i hope this helps someone in future
- The below piece of code is important to achieve this goal

  ```
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ```

---

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.dev.navigation.DistanceAscending;
import com.dev.navigation.DistanceDescending;
import com.dev.navigation.PriceAscending;
import com.dev.navigation.RatingAscending;
import com.dev.navigation.RatingDescending;

public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment{

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    private static int count=0;
    //Mandatory Constructor
    public Fragment1() {
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Log", "onCreate");

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container, false);
        Log.d("Log", "onCreateView");

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentb").setIndicator("Rating"),RatingAscending.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentc").setIndicator("Price"),PriceAscending.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentd").setIndicator("Distance"),DistanceAscending.class, null);
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("Log", "onStart");

        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                count++;
                Log.d("You clicked ", count+"time");


                RatingDescending fObj=new RatingDescending();
                //FragmentTransaction manager = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                //android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fObj);
                ft.commit();

                /*
                 *-------OVERLAPPING----FRAGMENT------CODE 
                 * RatingDescending fObj=new RatingDescending();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fObj);
                ft.commit();
                */
            }
        });
    }   

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("Log", "onResume");

    }
}
```